# promtail regex not match log with ANSI color

Tags: grafana-loki, promtail

I am using regular expressions to process my logs.

My promtail config is:

```yaml
- job_name: kubernetes-pods
  pipeline_stages:
    - docker: {}
    - regex:
         expression: '^(?P<timestamp>[0-9 :.-]+?) \| \\u001b\[0;00;[0-9]+m(?P<logLevel>[DIWEF])\\u001b\[0m \| (?P<traceID>.*) \| (?P<location>[^\s]+:\d+) \\u001b\[0;00;[0-9]+m(?P<message>.+)\\u001b\[0m.*$'
    - labels:
        timestamp: timestamp
        logLevel: logLevel
        traceID: traceID
        location: location
        message: message
```

My log is like：

```
09-04 18:22:07.415 | \u001b[0;00;32mI\u001b[0m |  | handler.go:383 \u001b[0;00;32mget all robot stop plan info\u001b[0m\n
```

I got the error message from promtail debug log:

```
level=debug ts=2023-09-06T01:27:27.313448004Z caller=regex.go:121 component=file_pipeline component=stage type=regex msg="regex did not match" input="09-04 18:22:07.415 | \u001b[0;00;32mI\u001b[0m |  | handler.go:383 \u001b[0;00;32mget all robot stop plan info\u001b[0m\n" regex="^(?P<timestamp>[0-9 :.-]+?) \\| \\\\u001b\\[0;00;[0-9]+m(?P<logLevel>[DIWEF])\\\\u001b\\[0m \\| (?P<traceID>.*) \\| (?P<location>[^\\s]+:\\d+) \\\\u001b\\[0;00;[0-9]+m(?P<message>.+)\\\\u001b\\[0m.*$"
```

But I tested the regex in Go and it was correct.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    logLine := `09-04 18:22:07.415 | \u001b[0;00;32mI\u001b[0m |  | handler.go:383 \u001b[0;00;32mget all robot stop plan info\u001b[0m\n`
    re := regexp.MustCompile(`^(?P<timestamp>[0-9 :.-]+?) \| \\u001b\[0;00;[0-9]+m(?P<logLevel>[DIWEF])\\u001b\[0m \| (?P<traceID>.*) \| (?P<location>[^\s]+:\d+) \\u001b\[0;00;[0-9]+m(?P<message>.+)\\u001b\[0m.*$`)
    match := re.FindStringSubmatch(logLine)

    if match != nil {
        groups := make(map[string]string)

        // 提取捕获组
        for i, name := range re.SubexpNames() {
            if name != "" {
                groups[name] = match[i]
            }
        }

        fmt.Printf("Timestamp: %s\n", groups["timestamp"])
        fmt.Printf("Log Level: %s\n", groups["logLevel"])
        fmt.Printf("Trace ID: %s\n", groups["traceID"])
        fmt.Printf("Location: %s\n", groups["location"])
        fmt.Printf("Message: %s\n", groups["message"])
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Log line does not match the expected format.")
    }
}
```

output:

```
Timestamp: 09-04 18:22:07.415
Log Level: I
Trace ID: 
Location: handler.go:383
Message: get all robot stop plan info
```

Who can tell me where the problem is? THX!

I want to get the result of running the regular expression correctly，like"

```
Timestamp: 09-04 18:22:07.415
Log Level: I
Trace ID: abc
Location: handler.go:383
Message: get all robot stop plan info
```

Comment: Aren't your promtail run with option `--config.expand-env=true` by chance? Because if yes, you need to double every backslash.

Comment: Outside of that you are interested best position to answer you own question: remove all the suspicious parts of regex so it matches, and introduce them one by one until parsing is broken once again. That way you'll know what exact construction causes problem.